# How do I get the next HTML element in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Let's say my HTML document is like:

```
<div class="headline">News</div>
<p>Some interesting news here</p>
<div class="headline">Sports</div>
<p>Baseball is fun!</p>
```

I can get the `headline` divs with the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "mypage.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css(".headline").each do |item|  
  puts item.text
end
```

But how do I access the content in the following `p` tag so that `News` is related to `Some interesting news here`, etc?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want [Node#next_element](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next_element):

```
doc.css(".headline").each do |item|
  puts item.text
  puts item.next_element.text
end
```

There is also `item.next`, but that will also return text nodes, where `item.next_element` will return only element nodes (like `p`).

Comment: I'm getting a `nil` object when I use `next_element`  **EDIT** It looks like the `"headline" div` is inside a `span`.  I will update the XML example

Comment: That did the trick.  I had to do `item.parent.next_element` because the headline div was inside a span tag.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to validate that HTML then. If I remember right divs aren't supposed to be inside span tags.

Comment: "item.next... will also return text nodes" was very useful to me, thanks. That was very unclear from the docs.